# What is SQL Query (T-SQL) which counts transaction status for particular Name against all categorical statuses available?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a table that looks like:

```
Columns : [District] [Name] [Status1] [Status2] [Status3]

Data: DistrictA    MrChan   1      1       1 

Data: DistrictB    MrFoo    1     0       2

Data: DistrictB    MsLucy   0     1       0
(sorry the table turns out unexpected after posting)

select StatusID, StatusCode from 
BookingStatus retrieves all categorical statuses Status1, Status2, Status3


select userid, DistrictA, StatusID from 
UnitBooking retrieve multiple rows which represent booking transactions.
```

In example above Ms Lucy has done 1 booking she would have 1 row in UnitBooking. Mr Foo have 3 rows and Mr Chan also have 3 rows.

Example Data:

```
select [userid], [username], [District], [StatusID] from UnitBooking

[1],[MrChan],[DistrictA],[1]

[1],[MrChan],[DistrictA],[2]

[1],[MrChan],[DistrictA],[3]

[2],[MrFoo],[DistrictB],[1]

[2],[MrFoo],[DistrictB],[3]

[2],[MrFoo],[DistrictB],[3]

[3],[MsLucy],[DistrictB],[2]


select [StatusID], [StatusCode] from BookingStatus

[1],[Status1]

[2],[Status2]

[3],[Status3]
```

What is the T-SQL that produces the result set?

Thanks a lot

Comment: please post some sample data for both tables

Comment: you want to create a table like this ? Or do you have tables and you want to extract data from them like this ?

Comment: I already have the tables and mechanisms in place which place data into the tables. I am trying to write an SQL for reporting

Comment: Than edit your question. Put sample data for both tables and put the desired output so we know what you have and what you want

Comment: @ChanFunChiat:please update question

Comment: Question updated. I omitted irrelevant transaction details like GUID,  booking dates, remarks etc so that the question is clearer on my intent

Comment: you are editing continously,which is rolling back all edits made

Comment: Ya I thought you could mean update the title as well. I have done final touch ups. So no more edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
district,
username,
sum(case when bs.statusid=1 then 1 else 0 end) 'status1',
sum(case when bs.statusid=2 then 1 else 0 end) 'status2',
sum(case when bs.statusid=3 then 1 else 0 end) 'status13'
from
unitbooking ub
join
BookingStatus Bs
on bs.statusid=ub.statusid
group by district,username
```

Comment: That is a smart use of 'case when'! Thank you

Comment: Suppose in future somebody added a fourth status row in BookingStatus table aka 'Status4'. What is SQL that dynamically reflect this new status, without modifying this SQL?

Comment: see this :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an SQL that works for my report but I am not good at what the STUFF function and XML PATH part do, except it works. Here goes:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((  SELECT ', SUM(CASE WHEN ub.BookingStatus=' 
                    + Cast(ItemID as nvarchar(128)) 
                    + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(StatusCode)
                    FROM customtable_BookingStatus
                    --WHERE ItemID Not In (1)
                    GROUP BY StatusCode
                            ,ItemID
                    ORDER BY ItemID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT usr.FullName, usi.District, '
        +'cnt.[OPEN] as [DUALLANGUAGE], cnt.BOOKED, cnt.CONFIRMED, cnt.SOLD from customtable__User usr
          left join customtable_Public_User_Info usi on usi.UserID = usr.UserID
          inner join '
        +'(SELECT ub.UserID,' + @cols 
        +'from customtable_UnitBooking ub
          join customtable_BookingStatus bs on bs.ItemID = ub.BookingStatus
          group by ub.UserId, ub.BookingStatus) '
        +'cnt on cnt.UserID = usr.UserID'
--Print @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Here's some value added conveniences:

-Support new entries in BookingStatus table dynamically. Still need to explicitly state the name of new column in final @query.

-Technically the names of new column could also be dynamic inside @query by adding an additional STUFF function with similar signature that retrieves plain comma separated columns. Here's the snippet:

```
DECLARE @colsForQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @colsForQuery = STUFF((  SELECT ',cnt.' + QUOTENAME(StatusCode) 
                    FROM customtable_BookingStatus
                    --WHERE ItemID Not In (1)
                    GROUP BY StatusCode
                            ,ItemID
                    ORDER BY ItemID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

produces this:

```
 cnt.[OPEN],cnt.[BOOKED],cnt.[SOLD],cnt.[CONFIRMED]
```

-My report has dual language but not easy if all columns are entirely dynamic

-Omit columns using 'WHERE ItemID Not In (1)' or remove it in @query

-Watch out for columns that clashes with T-SQL keyword, example I must encase [OPEN] because its keyword

Overall I think TheGameiswar is correct answer. I am just extending his solution based on the URL suggested inside comments.